# Twitter social sign-in Android

Tags: android, twitter

Friends, I followed the instructions for adding a signin Twitter button on my app, but I got an error.

I got the activity with the button, but when I pressed the button to return, I didn't get a request code.

First I followed the `sociallogin` helper in GitHub, but the app gave me an `na error`. I read about this code, and a put the following in my app:

```
  TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig("twitter api", "api secret");
    Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));
```

But now I can't get the request code to sign in.

This the part of the code:

```
  TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig("[KEY]", "[SECRET]");
    Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));
    iniciate();
```

The `iniciate` method has:

```
   tn_twitter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_twitter);
   twitterHelper = new TwitterHelper(this,MainActivity.this,"api code","secret code");
    btn_twitter.setOnClickListener(this);
```

What is my mistake? The GitHub script has no `Fabric` with the code, but now the app is shown on screen but not returning to de-sign-in `userId`.

Comment: Not super familiar with Twitter's API myself, but `iniciate()` may need to be spelled correctly as `initiate()`.

Comment: sorry i typed it´s right ... i´from brazil and here it´s correct.. just a user method...

Comment: Did you check the Twitter Kit 3 documentation? there's no need for Fabric any longer. https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/android/log-in-with-twitter